# SQLplus not connecting after Oracle 19c installation on RHEL giving error ORA-12154:

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle19c

Unable to connect using SQLplus after installation of Oracle.

```
[oracle@78787~]$ sqlplus  SYS/Oracle_1@cdb1 AS SYSDBA

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Dec 29 11:38:40 2021
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Adding few more details
I get connected  after getting the error and giving the username and password again, like below. The console prompts for entering username and password again.

```
[oracle@78787~]$ sqlplus  SYS/Oracle_1@cdb1 AS SYSDBA

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Dec 29 12:11:31 2021
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
**ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified**


Enter user-name: SYS as SYSDBA
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> exit;
```

I do not find tnsnames.ora file and sqlnet.ora  in the below path, but those are inside samples. And the ones inside samples looks like sample files, with most lines commented.

```
ls -lrt $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall 1536 Feb 13  2018 shrept.lst
drwxr-xr-x. 2 oracle oinstall   64 Dec 29 07:01 samples
```

Comment: Make sure that you create a `TNSNAME.ORA` file, and properly set `$ORACLE_HOME` parameter, and `listener` is running ...

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - while you are correct about tnsnameS.ora and $ORACLE_HOME, the listener has nothing to do with this error.  The nature of the error means the client never even got the necessary connection info. Thus, the request was never passed to the network and so never got anywhere near a listener.

Comment: Of course it has nothing to do with the current error, I've just added that as a consequent step which OP will probably encounter as a case @EdStevens

Comment: @Manu - show us the contents of your tnsnames.ora file and sqlnet.ora file located in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin.  Your error means exactly one of two things: Either there is not an entry for 'cdb1' in your tnsnames file, or there is no tnsnames file at all.  Read more about this error [here](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/troubleshooting-ora-12154/)